# Differences between Dynamo for Revit and Grasshoper for Rhino

Tags: revit-api, grasshopper

if there are experts users of both plug-ins, could someone please elaborate on the differences in the functionalities? Are there design tasks which can be solved/performed with the one but not with the other? I am not an expert user of any of them, and have worked only with Dynamo so far.
I am aware that both are algorithmic modelling tools, but also that much more than geometrical data can be accessed and modelled (with Dynamo this is definitely the case).
So I was wondering: are there areas/tasks which can be covered and solved with the one but not with the other, and are there some significant differences in the scope and depth of the tasks which can be achieved with the one but not with the other?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the main difference lies in the parent application they are running in, and it's general scope as modelling programs.

Grasshopper is very good at creating, modifying and processing geometry. But is not that good at managing "meta-data" and other non-geometric concepts.

Dynamo on the other hand, which mainly runs in BIM software (Revit, Civil...) is heavily influenced by this; it's very good at managing nested data structures like Dictionaries and other non-geometric types, but when it comes to geometry it lacks the advanced tools that Grasshopper provides.

Granted, there is a great community of 3rd party developers that do great stuff for both platforms, and will allow you to overcome most of the limitations of either, but my personal opinion would be that with the addition of [Rhino.Inside](https://www.rhino3d.com/features/rhino-inside/), Grasshopper is the way to go.